# Window 2008 server shared not accessible if Firewall is on

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, shares

I have folder to be shared on Window Server 2008.

If I disable the firewall then the Mac can see the folder. When I enable the firewall the Mac can no longer connect.

Which rules do I have to create in the firewall to allow access to the shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the firewall settings in the Windows Control Panel
2. Click "Allow Program through Windows Firewall"
3. Tick the box for "File and Printer Sharing"

Edit:

As you mention in your comment you may also need let through other services that provide authentication/authorization/discovery... for file sharing if you are not just using basic Windows file sharing.

Comment: thanks buddy  , By turning on just file services didn't worked 
i also added network discovery and netlogon as well and then it worked
thanks for the idea